Unable generate timestamp
I am trying to generate timestamp for my snapshots:
    default:
  image: docker:24.0.5
  services:
    - docker:24.0.5-dind
  before_script:
    - docker info

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"
  IMAGE_TAG: "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apk add python3
    - apk add py3-pip
    - pip3 install awscli --break-system-packages
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
  script:
    - echo $IMAGE_TAG
    - docker build -t repository .
    - docker tag repository:latest XXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/repository:$IMAGE_TAG
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
    - docker push XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/repository:$IMAGE_TAG

But for some reason, that doesn't return the value IMAGE_TAG: "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
Any ideas why it is not working?

Does IMAGE_TAG contain anything at all?
